# docker-compose.yml to dockerize the spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, data-jpa-test

*I want to dockerize my spring boot project. I created docker-compose.yml but ./mvnw clean package && docker-compose build && docker-compose up
When I run these commands, the test in the repository test class gives an error. I want to update the docker-compose.yml file accordingly.

I mean ./mvnw clean package && docker-compose build && docker-compose up
dockerize the project using these commands but my test class is throwing an error
*

```
MYSQLDB_USER=root
MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345
MYSQLDB_DATABASE=familybudgetapp
MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT=3307
MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT=3306

SPRING_LOCAL_PORT=8081
SPRING_DOCKER_PORT=8081



server.port=8081
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/familybudgetapptest
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show.sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true




server.port=8081
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/familybudgetapp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect



version: "3.8"

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - ${MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT}:${MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT}
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

  web_app:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - ${SPRING_LOCAL_PORT}:${SPRING_DOCKER_PORT}
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
            "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT/$MYSQLDB_DATABASE?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false",
            "spring.datasource.username" : "$MYSQLDB_USER",
            "spring.datasource.password" : "$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
            "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect",
            "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
          }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  db:





@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class SpendingRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    SpendingRepository spendingRepository;

    @Test
    @Sql({"/data.sql"})
    void findMostSpendingDetailsByDate_GivenDate_ReturnSpendings() throws ParseException {
        Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2001-06-01");
        Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2001-06-30");
        List<Spending> spendings = spendingRepository.findMostSpendingDetailsByDate(startDate, 
    endDate);
        assertEquals(5, spendings.size());
        assertEquals("tahafurkanunsal", spendings.get(0).getUser().getUsername());
    }
}
```

> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
> at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> 123 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
> at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
> 126 common frames omitted
>
> [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.308 s <<< FAILURE! - in tahafurkan.sandbox.familybudgetapp.repository.SpendingRepositoryTest
> [ERROR] findMostSpendingDetailsByDate_GivenDate_ReturnSpendings  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@56e78538 testClass = tahafurkan.sandbox.familybudgetapp.repository.SpendingRepositoryTest, locations = [], classes = [tahafurkan.sandbox.familybudgetapp.FamilyBudgetAppApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@731fae key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6f10d5b6, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@3f4faf53, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@7f8cd5fc, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@60157ffa, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@65f8f5ae, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@f52760f7], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
> Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException:
> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException:
> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
>
> [INFO]
> [INFO] Results:
> [INFO]
> [ERROR] Errors:
> [ERROR]   FamilyBudgetAppApplicationTests.contextLoads ▒ IllegalState Failed to load App...
> [ERROR]   SpendingRepositoryTest.findMostSpendingDetailsByDate_GivenDate_ReturnSpendings ▒ IllegalState
> [INFO]
> [ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
> [INFO]
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time:  16.885 s
> [INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-05T02:18:45+03:00
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project family-budget-app: There are test failures.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\PRO\Desktop\family-budget-app\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
> [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with your configuration, not the database connection.

You could try updating your substitutions in the json as follows: `$MYSQLDB_USER` with `${MYSQLDB_USER}`

```
{
            "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:${MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT}/${MYSQLDB_DATABASE}?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false",
            "spring.datasource.username" : "${MYSQLDB_USER}",
            "spring.datasource.password" : "${MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}",
            "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect",
            "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
}
```

Comment: actually no problem
When I remove the repository test class from the project there is no problem. but when I include the test file in the project, I get the errors I specified. I think I need to add test dependency to the yml file, but I couldn't do it. I'm looking for help.